# MariaDB CONNECT storage engine

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have a MariaDB running on one server that contains a particular table that I want somehow to have access to on another server on the same private network.The second server is also running MariaDB. Can this be achieved with the CONNECT storage engine? If so, can you point out any examples of how to do it? Thank you!

Comment: Unless you need "access" in the _same_ SQL query (eg, via `JOIN`), simply have two regular connections, one to each server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is possible:

First install the package. On Redhat and friends, run this command:

```
sudo yum install MariaDB-connect-engine
```

Or on Debian/Ubuntu and friends:

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-plugin-connect-engine
```

(Or should that say 'mariadb-plugin-connect'?)

Then log in to MariaDB and install the plugin:

```
INSTALL SONAME 'ha_connect';
```

Now create the `CONNECT` table locally:

```
CREATE TABLE my_connect_table (
   col1 type1 -- same columns as in your remote table
   ...
) 
ENGINE=CONNECT TABLE_TYPE=MYSQL dbname=the_db_name tabname=the_table_name 
CONNECTION='mysql://the_username:the_password@the_hostname';
```

Now you can `SELECT`, `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, `DELETE` etc. with that table as you wish. If you `DROP` this table, then you only `DROP` the local `CONNECT` table, not your remote table.

For reference, see:
[CONNECT MYSQL Table Type: Accessing MySQL/MariaDB Tables](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/connect-mysql-table-type-accessing-mysqlmariadb-tables/)

You might also want to consider the MariaDB [Spider storage engine](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/spider-storage-engine-overview/). The Connect engine can use any remote database system (Oracle, MSSQL, PostgreSQL, ...) if you install the ODBC driver, or it can even be e.g. a CSV file instead of an actual database system. The Spider engine is only for remote MariaDB databases. However, the advantage of Spider is that it has sharding features (i.e. allows distributing the data in a table across multiple servers) and supports XA transactions.

Comment: Thank you! What do you think of the performance? Nothing is cached locally, I guess.

Comment: BTW, what is the difference between CONNECT and SPIDER storage engine? Thanks.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov I don't have much experience with the performance of this. If you compare it with having two DB connections (one for the local and one for the remote DB), you are adding another network hop with this solution. But if you have to e.g. `JOIN` with the remote table, then this makes sense. It can also be quite convenient for the applications not to have to deal with two different DB connections.

Comment: @MartinDimitrov I added a bit at the end about the difference between Connect and Spider.